# Instead of getting my input content in alert I am getting an empty alert

Tags: javascript, input, alert

I am newby in programming. in my php project I want to use js to alert my input content by clicking on button. but the problem is that it alerts three times an empty content.

[image]

Even stopPropagation did not worked for me. I checked the spellings and every thing is ok. But I don't know what is wrong with it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button#addFolderBtn').click(function(event){
        var input=$('input#addFolderInput');
        alert(input.val());
    });
});
```

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: By itself, the code that you have provided will not cause that problem. If its being triggered 3 times, that implies that you have the same event handler loaded on the page three times.

Comment: Thank you dear friend.But  how can I fix it and check what loaded event causes this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me, your JQuery is not installed properly.
Try this code below

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
  let btn = document.getElementById('addFolderBtn');
  let input = document.getElementById('addFolderInput');
  btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    alert(input.value);
  });
});
```

If this works, then you need to fix JQuery CDN link and place it properly.

Comment: Thank you dear Bu Fahad. I run your code. but it didn't work either.